# Run application script in .bat file in task scheduler is not working

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

What is the missing in the script below that will not make it run the needed application??

```
runas /env /user:Administrator "Manager.exe"
```

when i double click the `.bat` file it requests a password, how to embed the admin password in the above command ??

Any idea ??

Comment: admin password for the exe?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `Run As Admin`. Just configure the task to use administrator account like below.

In task scheduler -> double click on task -> in opened task window left pane select `properties`. that
will open the below window. There, click on `Change user or group` button and select `Admin` account.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No it will not work, i tried it but there are some program that its not running, because that i tried the script ..

Comment: Somehow, am not getting what you saying. Why will it not work?